# Task Manager in Windows : Memory Tab

Tags: c#, windows, memory, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I created very simple program, and set up my computer to have limited amount of Virtual Memory. 32GB RAM and 4GB Virtual Memory. Then I made C# code to consume all NET memory.

```
List<HeapSizeAllocation> hsaList = new List<HeapSizeAllocation>();

public class HeapSizeAllocation
    {

        int[] _arr;
        int s1Gb = ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024) /sizeof(int); //1GB = 1024MB 1MB= 1024Kb 

        public void Test()
        {

            //Test simple array allocation
            _arr = new int[s1Gb * 2];

        }
    }
```

Click()=> Repeat until OutOfMemory Thrown

```
 HeapSizeAllocation hsa = new HeapSizeAllocation();
                hsaList.Add(hsa);

                hsa.Test();
```

Then I open TaskManager in Windows, and I still see 21 GB free, only 10 in use. Why?
[image]

Comment: How did you limited amount of Virtual Memory? Does swap file grow? Not used memory (like your arrays) can be swapped to disk.

Comment: System Properties\Advanced\Performance\Virtual Memory\Change\Custom Size \4Gb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4 GB you've specified through the System Properties settings is actually the size of the paging file(s) allowed. It's unfortunate that the setting is called "Virtual Memory", since it causes confusion with what the concept of *virtual memory* really means.

2 important things that need to be kept in mind:

- The default virtual address space for a process for a C# project built with Visual Studio on a x64 Windows box will be capped to 4 GB, due to the default `Platform target` default setting. You'd have to change this (eg to compile for the x64 platform) to see more being used
- As long as you only allocate data, but don't touch it in any way, the working set (namely how much RAM is actually used by your data) will stay quite low

I wrote an article specifically for the scenario you referenced (out of memory thrown on a machine with plenty of RAM, but lots of memory still left available) [here](https://mihai-albert.com/2019/04/21/out-of-memory-exception/). It explains things in detail.